# What is the pressure for full vacuum?

Tags: pressure, vacuum

I'm asked to make a calculation for a pressure can, so I made a calculation according the ASME VIII code.

In this code there is a difference between Internal and External pressure. And I am struggling with the external pressure section.

In my assignment the design pressure is 10 Barg Internal pressure and also Full Vacuum.

If I am correct Full Vacuum results into External pressure where a specific pressure is generated from the outside.

But what is the pressure I should take into account? What is the pressure value for full vacuum.

Or am I totally wrong about the Full Vacuum being External Pressure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Full Vacuum means External Pressure. You need to design the can for 1 bar (abs) external pressure (atmospheric pressure), unless noted otherwise in your assignment, with proper safety factors. In particular, you need to analyze the can for buckling.